# Reduce / fold over list of monoid but reducer returns Either

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

Ive found myself in the situation a couple of times where i have a reducer / combine fn like so:

```
  def combiner(a: String, b: String): Either[String, String] = {
    (a + b).asRight[String]
  }
```

Its a dummy implementation but the fn can fail so it returns an either. I then I have a list of values I want to pass through this with reduce / fold. The best I can come up with (assuming the List's type is a monoid) is this:

```
  def combine(items: Vector[String]) = {

    items.foldLeft(Monoid[String].empty.asRight[String]) { case (acc, value) =>
      acc.flatMap( accStr => combiner(accStr, value))
    }
  }
```

Its a bit clumsy and as its a fairly generic pattern I suspect there's a better way to do it using cats.

Comment: Do you want to fail fast with the first error? Or you want to accumulate them too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [foldM](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Foldable.html). Your code would then look approximately like this:

```
Foldable[Vector].foldM(items, "")(combiner)
```

The `foldM` method has the signature

```
def foldM[G[_], A, B](fa: F[A], z: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ G[B])(implicit G: Monad[G]): G[B]
```

so in your case, the type(-constructor) parameters would unify as follows:

- `G[X] = Either[String, ?]`
- `A = String`
- `B = String`
- `F[X] = Vector[X]`

so that `f: (A, B) => G[B]` would become `f: (String, String) => Either[String, String]`, which is exactly the type of `combiner` when it's converted into a function.