# Folding a sequence with a binary operation that returns Future

Tags: scala, collections, concurrency, future, fold

Suppose I've got a function `op: (Int, Int) => Future[Int]` and need to write a new function `foo` :

```
def foo(xs: Seq[Int], 
        zero: Int, 
        op: (Int, Int) => Future[Int]): Future[Int] = ???
```

`foo` should work as `foldLeft` and apply `op` sequentially to all elements in `xs`, e.g.:

```
val op: (Int, Int) => Future[Int] = (x, y) => Future(x + y)
val xs = (1 to 10)
val fut = foo(xs, 0, op) // should return Future of 55
fut.value // Some(Success(55))
```

How would you implement `foo` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why the other answer was deleted - but with **plain Scala** this works for me:

```
 def foo(xs: Seq[Int], zero: Int, op: (Int, Int) => Future[Int]): Future[Int] =  

    xs.foldLeft(Future.successful(zero))((a, b) => a.flatMap(op(_, b)))
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 5):

Try [`foldM`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56452854/5205022) from cats:

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

def foo(xs: Seq[Int], zero: Int, op: (Int, Int) => Future[Int]): Future[Int] =
  Foldable[List].foldM(xs.toList, zero)(op)
```

Comment: Thanks. Good example of why `cats` are useful but I would prefer a plain Scala solution for now.

Answer (score 2):

Without using an external library:

Implement a "special" `foldLeft`:

```
def foldLeft[Int](xs: Seq[Int], z: Int)(op: (Int, Int) => Future[Int]): Future[Int] = {
 def f(xs: Seq[Int], accF: Future[Int]): Future[Int] = xs match {
   case Seq()   => accF
   case x +: xs => accF.flatMap(acc => f(xs, op(acc, x)))
 }

 f(xs, Future.successful(z))
```

}

And using it:

```
def foo(xs: Seq[Int], 
    zero: Int, 
    op: (Int, Int) => Future[Int]): Future[Int] = foldLeft(xs, zero)(op)
```